# Locust-plugins; Uncaught exception in event handler: TypeError: fire_deprecated_request_handlers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, locust

I've built a working locust-plugins web-driver script and was attempting to add some transactional timers and when I run the script I'm getting an error:

[2022-01-03 10:34:55,525] LHTU05CD943125T/ERROR/root: Uncaught exception in event handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\locust\event.py", line 40, in fire
handler(**kwargs)
TypeError: fire_deprecated_request_handlers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

The script continues to run but at every event call I see the above error.
I'm using locust version 2.5.1 and locust-plugins version 2.1.1.

```
@task
def open_digipass_homepage(self):
    self.clear()

    # CALL THIS ONCE
    start_time = time.monotonic()

    self.client.get("https://myurl-stage.com/")

    self.environment.events.request.fire(
        request_type="transaction",
        name="T000_SitePage",
        response_time=(time.monotonic() - start_time) * 1000,
        response_length=0,
        exception=None
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self.environment.events.request.fire` call is missing an argument it's expecting called `context`. This may or may not be a bug (not sure something like this should be required, if it is), but you should be able to work around it. Here's the documentation on the event signature:

http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request

Which links to this page on what the Context is supposed to be:

http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#request-context

Looks like it's a dictionary with whatever stuff you want to get passed around. Based on [some code in the tests](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/cce0d29b90e5e9f9dad7a7b96b25a393923c4a16/locust/test/test_runners.py#L287) I'd assume adding even just `context={}` to your call should work. Something like this:

```
self.environment.events.request.fire(
    request_type="transaction",
    name="T000_SitePage",
    response_time=(time.monotonic() - start_time) * 1000,
    response_length=0,
    exception=None,
    context={}
)
```

Comment: context is (somewhat ironically) mandatory in some cases due to the backwards compatibility with the legacy events (request_success/_failure). Once they are removed, context will become properly optional.